# Developing global tooltip

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have something like this currently: (myTooltip is some extension of ngbTooltip that allows to provide context)

```
..component1:
    <div [myTooltip]="tip" [myTooltipContext]="{...}">
    <ng-template #tip let-param="param">
        <tip-component param="param"></tip-component>
    </ng-template>

..component2:
    <div [myTooltip]="tip" [myTooltipContext]="{...}">
    <ng-template #tip let-param="param">
        <tip-component param="param"></tip-component>
    </ng-template>

..component3:
    <div [myTooltip]="tip" [myTooltipContext]="{...}">
    <ng-template #tip let-param="param">
        <tip-component param="param"></tip-component>
    </ng-template>
```

You see that this is code duplication and I wish to have just something like:

```
<div [myTooltip]="{...}"> // no template reference here and no template in file at all
```

Trying to write this directive:

```
export class MyTooltipDirective extends NgbTooltip {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.ngbTooltip = ???? /*need to provide here TemplateRef */
    }
}
```

E.g. in angularjs I would put template to $templateCache, what can I do here?

For now one option I see is in some root file add template and put it to Service as a field), so i can do this.ngbTooltip = SomeService.tempalteRef -- but this looks very tricky.

**Update, my solution**

NgbTooltip opens TooltipWindowComponent in which it injects template, I decided to change this and open my own window component instead. This solves problem -- but requires some code duplication cause of private methods in NgbTooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `myTooltip` input to whatever you want parameter.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awg48u-pa4o1t?file=app%2Fmy-tooltip.component.ts

```js
import {Component, Host, ViewChild, TemplateRef, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTooltip } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'myTooltip, [myTooltip]',
  template: `
  <ng-content>
  </ng-content>
  <ng-template>Hello {{myTooltip}}</ng-template>
  `
})
export class MyTooltipComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() myTooltip: string = '';

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: false}) template: TemplateRef<void>;

  ngAfterViewInit () {
   this.bindTemplete()
  }

  bindTemplete() {
    if (this.ngbTooltop) {
        this.ngbTooltop.ngbTooltip = this.template;
    }
  }
  constructor(@Host() private ngbTooltop: NgbTooltip) {

  }
}
```

```html
..component1:
    <div ngbTooltip myTooltip="A">

..component2:
    <div ngbTooltip myTooltip="B">

..component3:
    <div ngbTooltip myTooltip="C">
```

Comment: I can pass template... I do not want to pass it, cause it always same.

Comment: Yes, now only declaration the template once in `MyTooltipComponent `.

Comment: Sorry, the before link is wrong. please check the new link.

Comment: k got this. thing i dont like is that i will have TemplateRef in each directive instance (and on each page there are lots of these)

Comment: Though i didnt go this way, this is at least something that can be helpful...

Answer (score 3):

Hi Try this I am creating one tooltip directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appStickytooltip]',
  exportAs: 'appStickytooltip'
})
export class StickytooltipDirective extends NgbTooltip {
  @Input() stickyPopover: TemplateRef<any>;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.ngbTooltip = this.stickyPopover;
}
```

}

in the template, you have ten component each component you have call directive like that:

```
<h5 class="tile-sub-heading" appStickytooltip popoverClass="customClass" placement="top-left" [appStickytooltip]="'Hello i am tooltip'">Hove Over Me</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without a directive by implementing a hover text setter:

```
<div *ngFor="let o of someObjects">
    <div [ngbTooltip]="tooltip" (hover)="setTooltipText('I\'m a tooltip!')"></div>
</div>

<ng-template #tooltip>
    <div>{{tooltipText}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

```
tooltipText = '';


setTooltipText(text: string){
  this.tooltipText = text;
}
```

This way you can set the tooltip with the same look for all the components and the message is dynamically set.

Comment: I know how to have dynamic text, I know how to pass context object etc. I do not want to have same <ng-template> in each component.

Comment: You can do the tooltip using css only if you want the ng template to be not present in all your components

Comment: I hope you understand that I use ngbTooltip for reason, there is not just text... Lets say I have 10 components with 10 same ng-template's now and want to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export class MyTooltipDirective extends NgbTooltip {
    constructor(tmpl: TemplateRef,
                tooltip: NgbToolTip) {
       this.tooltip= this.tmpl;
    }
}
```